# AddThis Pinterest button error

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I have an issue with the Pinterest button. The first time its clicked it works but when the page is reloaded I get the error:

```
TypeError: a.split is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

...meo.com/%s"};if(w=="facebook"&&isNaN(d)){w="facebook_url";}return!d?null:((E[w]|...
```

The website its doing it on is www.artfido.com

Comment: Facing same problem right now! Did you managed to fix it yet ?

Comment: I had the same problem but as of today it seems to be solved. Guess it was a problem at AddThis-side.